# HTML&JavaScript: как вынести элемент за пределы отображающеся HTML-страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу сделать выдвижное меню (hamburger-menu) без использования сторонних плагинов. 
И сразу первая проблема: как вынести `<div>` за пределы отображающейся страницы?
Насколько я сейчас представляю, по нажатию кнопки я буду через JavaScript-анимацию перемещать этот `<div>` в видимую область.

Comment: код бы добавили

Comment: его ещё пока нет, я только продумываю принцип.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем списку, который хотим скрывать\показывать, плавность (время задаете свое):

```
transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
```

И добавляем трансформацию `transform: translateX(-100%);`. Список будет вынесен за body.

При клике - добавляем всему блоку `nav` активный класс `'on'`, при котором трансформация меняет свое значение с -100% на 0%:

```
transform: translateX(0%);
```

Пример:

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
  var nav = $(this).closest('nav');
  
  if(!nav.hasClass('on')){
    nav.addClass('on');
  }else {
    nav.removeClass('on');
  }
});
```

```css
nav ul {
  width: 200px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

nav.on ul {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}


/* Доп. стилизация для наглядности */
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav button {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <nav>
    <button class="trigger">btn</button>
    <ul>
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <main>
  </main>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за время, потраченное на написание ответа! Вы бы не могли дать краткий комментарий о том, как решили поставленную задачу? Насколько я вижу, Вы использовали CSS-анимацию.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, добавила краткий комментарий в ответ. Смысл в том, что при помощи небольшого скрипта, мы проверяем навигацию на активный класс и в зависимости от наличия\отсутствия добавляем\удаляем класс `on`. Появление\исчезание списка осуществляется при помощи свойства `transform: translateX();`, 0% - меню видно, 100% - меню скрыто за пределами документа. Плавность осуществляется при помощи свойства `transition`

Comment: Отлично, теперь всё понятно. Ещё раз спасибо Вам за ответ :)